# Image in Kivy Scrollview isn't scorllable

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a notebook app using kivy, where the user will be able to scroll the sheet up and down and write on it. I tried using ScrollView, but it doesn't seem to work - I wanted the sheet image to be stretched to the width of the window and as the height is greater than the width - have the image scrollable up and down. What happened instead was this:

[image]

I would really appreciate anyone looking into the code and trying the figure out what I was doing wrong :)

python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from PIL import Image as Image1
from kivy.uix.image import Image

GUI = Builder.load_file('style.kv')
Window.size = (1000, 200)

img_size = Image1.open("images/notebook.png").size


class NotebookScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.rows = 1
        super(NotebookScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_size_for_notebook(self, **kwargs):
        global img_size
        width, height = Window.size
        return width, (img_size[0] * height / width)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return NotebookScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<NotebookScreen>
    FloatLayout:
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .05
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            id: tool_bar
            cols: 1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            id: notebook_grid
            size_hint: 1, .95
            pos_hint: {"top": .95, "left": 0}
            cols: 1

            ScrollView:

                Image:
                    id: notebook_image
                    source: 'images/notebook.png'
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: root.get_size_for_notebook()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `size` of the `Image` in your `kv`, but it is having no effect, since `size_hint` over-rules `size`. The default `size_hint` is `(1,1)`, so no scrolling is done (the `Image` is constrained to fit in the `ScrollView`). To allow your `size` to take effect, just add:

```
size_hint: None, None
```

to the `Image` in your `kv`.